# How to prepopulate Realm database with data?

Tags: react-native, realm

I have a file of data scraped from the web, that was generated using python script.
How can I load it into my Realm react native database?
I have stumbled upon ideas that it can be loaded from JSON file without any modifications, is it possible, how to do this?

How can I specify path to the file in react native?
How can I parse a file in react native?

Update:
Could you suggest me the general work flow for work with data in React Native? I haven't found useful manuals for that.
I wonder, should I parse files from React native (generic scripts), in this case how to specify path to them, or should I work with them in the specific platform (from Andriod /iOS project)?

Comment: What kind of "a file of data scraped from the web" do you want to "import"? Is it a JSON? What have you tried?

Comment: @EduardoMacêdo I can convert it to JSON format. How to work with files in react native: should I load process them from java script, or do it in Android && iOS projects?

Comment: I'm starting to think this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). By prepopulate the Realm database you mean you want to load some data into the local Realm database when the user opens your app for the first time? Have you read the [Realm documentation](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/)? The process to put data into the database is the first example the doc shows.

Comment: @EduardoMacêdo Yes! I have read the documentation for Realm react native from start till the end.  I don't know how to get data from file in react native in order to apply steps from the first example to that data, also should I apply them at all, if for example it is possible to use JSON for database initialization

Comment: In the introduction they show that you can use `realm.create` to insert a new entry into the database. So you can just "import" your JSON file using the Node.js `require` function, parse that JSON using the `JSON.parse(myJson)`, create a schema for your data, and then do a for loop for each entry you have calling the `realm.create` function with the schema name and the object.

Comment: @EduardoMacêdo sounds good, could you, please, write this as answer with more details, and some example would be great. I think this might be very useful for other, as I have found that this question is rather frequent

Comment: Do you mean you want to import a file to realm database and copy filled realm database to your app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I came out with the valid workflow for providing repopulated database.
1. **Convert your data to json format**, as json files can be imported directly using node's npm `require` method. (I had file in csv format, and wrote python script to convert it into json), so your file should look like this:

```
{"key0": ["property0", "property1"], "key1": ["property0", "property1"]...}
```

actually you create json file having schema of your database in mind, example file will map to the following schema:

```
const MyDBSchema = {
    name: 'MyEntity',
    primaryKey: 'key',
    properties: {
      key:  'string',
      property0: 'string',
      property1: 'int',
      property2: 'int',
      property3: 'int'
    }
};
```

as you can see, I load properties: property0, property1 from son file, other properties are initialized when I create database.
2. **Create you database for the first time:**
this includes database generation and selection of place where to put it (be careful on where to put it, as there are limited choices here).
**The key element here is that we create database only once, only if there is no database, we use `RNFS` module for that**.
We algorithm is fairly strait forward: if file exists - open it, otherwise create and open it.

```
export async function openDB() {
    realm = await Realm.open({
        path: RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/myDBname.realm',
        schema: [MySchema],

    });
    RNFS.exists(RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/myDBname.realm').then(exists => {
        if(!exists) {
          createDB(realm);
        }
    });
    return realm;
}
```

Database creation is described on the Realm's web page, in any case here is my code snippet for that, so you could see how it maps to the overall picture:

```
let entities = require('../../data/myJsonFileForDB');
export function createDB(realm){
try {
    console.log("Creating DB");
    console.log("db path:" + realm.path);
    realm.write(() => {
        for (let entity in entities) {
            let property0 = entities['property0'][0];
            let property1 = parseInt(entities['property0'][1]);
            realm.create('myEntity', 
              {
                property0: property0,
                property1: property1,
                property2: 0,
                property3: 0,
              }, true);
          }
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
        console.log("Error on creation");
    }
};
```

Comment: Where did you get the .realm file though? I thought you're supposed to read .json file.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the realm website. It looks like you just need to convert whatever you have to a JSON object that works for what you are doing and then define it as a schema and create a new Realm object from it.

```
const Realm = require('realm');

class Person {}
Person.schema = {
    name: 'Person',
    primaryKey: 'name',
    properties: {
        name: 'string',
        age: {type: 'int', default: 0},
    },
};

const realm = new Realm({schema: [Person]});

// Query
let people = realm.objects('Person', 'age >= 17');
people.length // => 0

// Write
realm.write(() => {
    savedPerson = realm.create('Person', {
        name: 'Hal Incandenza',
        age: 17,
    });
});

// Queries are updated in real-time
people.length // => 1
let pups = realm.objects('Dog').filtered('age < 2');
```